# Get an object from dynamic list object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable list as follows,

```
var gfList = {};
gfList['1'] = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.878113, -87.629798),
    radius: 400
};
gfList['2'] = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.714352, -74.005973),
    radius: 250
};
gfList['3'] = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.052234, -118.243684),
    radius: 650
};
gfList['4'] = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(49.25, -123.1),
    radius: 550
};
```

I want an object from this list based on my Select box value selected . 
The following code is working, if I use Static Value

```
$('#geofenceId').on("change", function() {
    var geofenceId = '1';
    var gfence = gfList[geofenceId];
    alert('Values are : ' + geofenceId + ',' + gfence.center + '--' + gfence.radious);
});
```

but this code not working, if i get the value from select Box

```
$('#geofenceId').on("change", function() {
    var geofenceId = $('#geofenceId').val();
    var gfence = gfList[geofenceId];
    alert('Values are  : ' + geofenceId + ',' + gfence.center + '--' + gfence.radious);
});
```

I got error as follows for above code in browser console

> TypeError: gfence is undefined

Comment: Have you confirmed that the option values are '1', '2', '3', etc.? What does the alert show?

Comment: Let us know what is being return by `$('#geofenceId').val()`

Comment: Not sure why you're using string indices instead of integers....

Comment: @Cory : Yes the alert shows as 1

Comment: @RahilWazir the Alert Shows for $('#geofenceId').val() as 1

Comment: @Blazemonger I have Changed to Integer Index also.. But the result is same....

Comment: @SCKannan Working fine here http://jsfiddle.net/rahilwazir/Ls98ng7y/

Comment: @RahilWazir Thanks.. tracked the issue.. in Select Box value an space is added. After Trim it is working fine..

Comment: BTW this `var gfList = {}; gfList['1'] = { ... }` is not a "list", it's an **object** masquerading as an "associative array" where the object properties names are `'1'`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to handle your data with an array instead of a JSON object.

Then, when change event is triggered, get value of your option with `$(this).find(':selected').val()`, apply a `parseInt()` on it and finally get your entry from your structure with its fresh index.

Here is a sample of JS code:

```
var data = new Array();
data.push({ id : "foo", extra : "extra data"});
// prepare your data here

$('.js-dropdown').on('change', function() {
    var option = $(this).find(':selected');
    var index = parseInt(option.val());

    console.log('outcome: ' + data[index]);
});
```

Of course, using an array force you to order your data. Otherwise, use your original JSON object. However, I think you must parse inputs to ensure your code to work.